# Comparing WORD characteristics

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, portable-executable

I am trying to read PE headers, and want to see if an exe has ASLR enabled.

I am currently doing :

```
if (PE.FileHeader->OptionalHeader.DllCharacteristics == IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE)
        std::cout << "ASLR is enabled :)" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "ASLR is disabled >:(" << std::endl;
```

However, I always get "ASLR is disabled >:(", even if I know for a fact ASLR is enabled.

I know this has to do with my operator, but how do I test and see if a PE header has a certain WORD character?

Comment: Its important to keep in mind ASLR will also be disabled regardless of the contents of DllCharacteristics *IF* the module is missing a .reloc section.  See Raymond Chen's blog for more info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170607-00/?p=96295

Comment: Thanks @byteptr, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DllCharacteristics` is a bitmask, it can contain multiple flags enabled. Your check must use the bitwise `&` operator instead of the `==` operator:

```
if (PE.FileHeader->OptionalHeader.DllCharacteristics & IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE)
    std::cout << "ASLR is enabled :)" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "ASLR is disabled >:(" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Noting that with a lot of bitflags that are themselves a composition of simpler flags (or an bitmasked enum) you actually need to & (with a mask) and then ALSO test for equality.

Comment: @ChrisBecke - yes, but in case simply flag (exactly one bit) enough just `&`

Answer (score 1):

Found it working by below way in case of multibit flags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE is highest bit in DllCharacteristics :

```
if (PE.FileHeader->OptionalHeader.DllCharacteristics & 
    (IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE|
     IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE) == 
    IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE)
    std::cout << "ASLR is enabled :)" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "ASLR is disabled >:(" << std::endl;
```